# Calling a method on all ScrollViewers within Grid Templates

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8.1

i'm developing a Windows 8.1 Store App in which i have multiple GridViews, All these grid views have the same Item Template containing a ScrollViewer.
What i want to do is, calling a method like ZoomToFactor on all these ScrollViewers, of course, whithout having a direct reference to it.
Is there any way to get a list of references to all these ScrollViewers or something?

I'm Using Visual Studio 2013 with .Net Framework 4.5.1 .

Answer (score 0):

How about using the mediator pattern? Call ZoomToFactor on the mediator and let it notify it's subscribers (ViewModels, assuming you use MVVM) to update. You can bind the relevant properties of the GridViews to their ViewModels.

Comment: I'm new to Store App development, I'm not using MVVM, i think i should learn more about it, i can understand that there is no way to do it without MVVM?

Comment: You don't have to use MVVM. Since you mentioned not wanting to have a reference to the gridviews I assumed you were using it. It is however highly recommended to invest some time in learning MVVM. It will make your life a lot easier when your application starts to grow. This might help you get started: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx)

Comment: But back to your question: how is your application structured? Are the GridViews all in the same container?

Comment: yes, they are in a ScrollViewer representing groups of items, the ScrollViewer i need to have access to are in the ItemTemplate.